# how to find checked out files in a clearcase (windows) snapshot view?

Tags: clearcase, cleartool

On Unix in a dynamic view, I run the following to find checked out files:

```
cleartool lsco -s -cview -me -avobs
```

In a windows snapshot view, this use of -avobs doesn't appear to work.  On a vob by vob basis I can run:

```
cleartool lsco -s -cview -me -all
```

which returns the checked out names to me for that vob.

Is there a way to tell what vobs have checkouts in a Windows snapshot view?  (not sure if Windows vs. Unix is a factor here).  I'd like to script the lsco, executing it in each of the vobs in question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering each vobs is a direct child directory of the root directory of your snapshot view, all you need to do is to:

- list every direct child directory (whose name represents a vob)
- execute your cleartool lsco within each of those directories.

This is consistent with the issue around the usage of "`-cview -avobs`" mention in [this technote](https://www-304.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1IC41302):

> Local fix
>
> Do not use `lsco -cview -avobs`.
> You needs to run `cleartool lsco` while cd'd in each Unix vob  in the Windows snapshot view.

Comment: Thanks, that's simple enough.