# list of views that has checkouts in a stream

Tags: clearcase

how to find the list of views that has checkouts in a stream in clearcase?

1.) cleartool lsstream -l streamname
Gives the list of views

2.) I need to create snapshot view and then list checkouts in that view

cleartool lsco -r

Is there any way to::

ie..,List of all views that has checkouts in a stream

Comment: I also tried:   cleartool lsco -l -avobs -brtype  Streamname                                     But it didnt give the list of views:(

Answer (score 0):

No, unless those views are dynamic (in which case, you can mount them and do a `cleartool lsco`)
For snapshot view, you would need to [access to a local loaded snapshot view](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8749324/6309), which can quickly become too expensive to do.

Another approach would be to

- [list activities in a stream](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23168973/6309)
- for each activity, [describe the activity](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10632818/6309) (listing each versions referenced in it)

If one of those version is checked out, it will be displayed as such, with the name of the view.

---

The other approach is to consider to vob which includes the roots of the components used in a stream:

```
cleartool descr -l vob:\aVobTag
```

That would list *any* view (UCM or not) which has at least one checked out file.
You can then describe each view (`cleartool lsstream -view aview`) in order to check if that view is an UCM view on the expected stream.

Comment: I have checked that too..       Describing an activity gives:    1.) Activity currently set in the view       2.) Change set versions  of that activity.                       3.)  Also tried , cleartool ls -l activityname | grep -in checkout    gives only the files that were checkout..        But how to find the view-tag or view name that has done those checkouts?

Comment: @harish by describing each checked out version (or opening their version tree): the name of the view should be listed there.